# Bootstrap modal dialog not appear on the center of a screen

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make a modal dialog and used the bootstrap modal dialog. But when I applied to my code and run it, the dialog appears not on the center of a screen, but on the right side of the screen, like image below:

[image]

I have import this link and script to my code in `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<link href="carousel.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

And in the View, I wrote this:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div id="container">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
                <img class="first-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img class="second-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==">
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="container marketing">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">
                <img class="img-rounded" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" width="750" height="250">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 

<div class="container">
    <h2>Modal Example</h2>
    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Why is it happen like this? Thank you.

Comment: You should add a www.jsfiddle.net and you will get help much faster!

Answer (score 1):

Your Code is working properly.
Dialog box appears in center successfully in this code.
May any other class of your project is interrupting your dialog box.